# How to hide the root page from public

Tags: php

I have a php website and i have pages like

> xyz.com/cat/page1.html 
>   xxyz.com/cat/page2.html

Now I want to restrict this page xyz.com/cat/ from the visitors. How do I achieve this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the root directory, then no one will be able to access anything in that folder including images and other media. Yes create an .htaccess file inside the directory you wish to deny access to. Enter the following:

order allow,deny

allow from 127.0.0.1

deny from all